# NOAUTH Authentication required when connecting to Redis Sentinel with LettuceConnectionFactory

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-redis

I am trying to connect to a Redis server using sentinel with password. I got RedisCommandExecutionException: NOAUTH Authentication required when calling `redisTemplate.opsForValue().get("key")`

```
Exception in thread "Thread-6" org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Unable to connect to Redis on localhost:6379; nested exception is com.lambdaworks.redis.RedisCommandExecutionException: NOAUTH Authentication required.
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory.createLettuceConnector(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:544)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory.initConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:213)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory.getSharedConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory.getConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:189)
```

This is how I configured the connection factory:

```java
RedisSentinelConfiguration sentinelConfiguration = new RedisSentinelConfiguration().master("mymaster").sentinel("localhost", 26379);
LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory = new LettuceConnectionFactory(sentinelConfiguration);
lettuceConnectionFactory.setDatabase(1);
lettuceConnectionFactory.setPassword("foobared");
```

When I tried using `JedisConnectionFactory`, it works.

It looks like the password is not set when using `LettuceConnectionFactory` with sentinel.

I'm using spring-data-redis 1.7.2.

UPDATE:

I checked the code in `DefaultLettucePool` and saw that the password is not used in generating `RedisURI` when sentinelConfiguration is involved. When I modified the code as following, it works now.

DefaultLettucePool:

```java
private RedisURI getRedisURI() {

    if (isRedisSentinelAware()) {
        return LettuceConverters.sentinelConfigurationToRedisURI(sentinelConfiguration, password, getDatabase());
    }

    return createSimpleHostRedisURI();
}
```

And in LettuceConverters:

```java
public static RedisURI sentinelConfigurationToRedisURI(RedisSentinelConfiguration sentinelConfiguration, String password, int database) {
    Assert.notNull(sentinelConfiguration, "RedisSentinelConfiguration is required");

    Set<RedisNode> sentinels = sentinelConfiguration.getSentinels();
    RedisURI.Builder builder = null;
    for (RedisNode sentinel : sentinels) {

        if (builder == null) {
            builder = RedisURI.Builder.sentinel(sentinel.getHost(), sentinel.getPort(), sentinelConfiguration.getMaster()
                    .getName());
        }
        else {
            builder.withSentinel(sentinel.getHost(), sentinel.getPort());
        }
    }

    if (password != null) {
        builder = builder.withPassword(password);
    }
    builder.withDatabase(database);

    return builder.build();
}
```

Comment: That's a bug. I created [DATAREDIS-524](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREDIS-524) to track the issue.

Comment: great to hear that, thank you!